# Transform n columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas

i am looking for a way to disaggregate data from a single row in a **pandas df**.

My data looks like this

edit: *n* stands for an unspecified number, e.g. in my working dataset I have 8 plots giving me 8 x 2 = 16 columns I would like to transform.

```
data = {
        'key':['k1', 'k2'],
        'plot_name_1':['name', 'name'],
        'plot_area_1':[1,2],
        'plot_name_2':['name', 'name'],
        'plot_area_2':[1,2],
        'plot_name_n':['name', 'name'],
        'plot_area_n':[1,2]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

And I would like to end up here, adding an extra column to identify the plot number:

```
data = {
        'key':['k1','k1','k1', 'k2', 'k2', 'k2'],
        'plot_number':['1', '2', 'n','1', '2', 'n'],
        'plot_name':['name', 'name','name', 'name','name', 'name'],
        'plot_area':[1,2,1,2,1,2],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['plot_name', 'plot_area'], i='key', j='plot_number', sep='_')`

Comment: @mozway - does not account for `plot_name_n`, and `plot_area_n` as intended.

Comment: @ScottC I thought `n` was a generic term for any number, but easy to handle (I see @Mustafa did it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) can do this:

```py
In [160]: pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=["plot_name", "plot_area"],
                          i="key", j="plot_number",
                          sep="_", suffix=r"(?:\d+|n)").reset_index()
Out[160]:
  key plot_number plot_name  plot_area
0  k1           1      name          1
1  k2           1      name          2
2  k1           2      name          1
3  k2           2      name          2
4  k1           n      name          1
5  k2           n      name          2
```

where

- "stubnames" are the common column prefix names to capture
- "sep" is the separator after those prefixes

  - "_" in your case
- "suffix" is what's expected after the separator

  - one or more digits, or literal "n" in your case; if "n" was symbolic, you can have `suffix=r"\d+"` there
- "i" argument is the "index" (i.e., the identifier variables)
- "j" signifies the name under which the suffixes are gathered.

---

As an aside, we need to paranthesise the regex when multiple suffixes are possible because of the way pandas uses the `suffix` [under the hood when constructing the regex](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.2/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py#L501):

```py
regex = rf"^{re.escape(stub)}{re.escape(sep)}{suffix}$"
```

We see that `suffix` is interpolated directly, and an alternator (i.e., `|`) in it will see the left side as, e.g., not only `\d+` but also what comes from stub & sep, too.

Comment: Suffix can be `.`

Comment: agreed (`.+` for genericness) but if some stubs for some reason need to be excluded, explicit pattern might help

Answer (score 5):

One option is to reshape with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using a regular expression to capture the groups:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index='key', 
    names_to = ('.value', 'plot_number'), 
    names_pattern = r"(.+)_(.+)")
)
  key plot_number plot_name  plot_area
0  k1           1      name          1
1  k2           1      name          2
2  k1           2      name          1
3  k2           2      name          2
4  k1           n      name          1
5  k2           n      name          2
```

The `.value` determines which parts of the columns remains as headers